# Spring mvc Autowiring fails

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

**TrackerRepoImpl.java**

```
    @Repository("TrackerRepo")
    public class TrackerRepoImpl implements TrackerRepo { //repository interface implementation

        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        @Override
        public Session getCurrentSession() {    
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }

        @Override
        public void save(Event event) {
            getCurrentSession().save(event);
        }
    }
```

**TrackerServiceImpl.java**

```
    @Service("TrackerService")
    public class TrackerServiceImpl implements TrackerService { //service interface implementation

        @Autowired
        private TrackerRepo repo;

        @Override
        @Transactional
        public void save(Event event) {
            repo.save(event);
        }

    }
```

**RootConfig.java**

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.tracker"},excludeFilters={@Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION,value=EnableWebMvc.class)})
    public class RootConfig {

        @Bean  //session factory bean
        public LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean(DataSource dataSource)
        {
            LocalSessionFactoryBean bean=new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
            bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
            Properties properties=new Properties();
            properties.setProperty("dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
            bean.setHibernateProperties(properties);
            bean.setPackagesToScan("com.tracker");
            return bean;
        }

        @Bean  //datbase details
        public DataSource dataSource()
        {
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource=new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/tracker");
            dataSource.setUsername("root");
            dataSource.setPassword("root");

            return dataSource;
        }
       @Bean
       @Autowired
       public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
          HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
          txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

          return txManager;
       }

        @Bean
        public BeanPostProcessor persistenceTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
        }
    }
```

errors:

```
Jun 29, 2015 1:33:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/tracker] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread] with root cause
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
    at com.tracker.web.dao.TrackerRepoImpl.getCurrentSession(TrackerRepoImpl.java:22)
    at com.tracker.web.dao.TrackerRepoImpl.save(TrackerRepoImpl.java:27)
    at com.tracker.web.service.TrackerServiceImpl.save(TrackerServiceImpl.java:22)
    at com.tracker.web.controllers.MainController.submitPlannedPage(MainController.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The transactional stuff is because you haven't configured a transaction manager and you are missing `@EnableTransactionManagement` on your configuration class. The class not found, is probably due to eclipse not properly syncing classes.

Comment: updated the changes you suggested. still there are errors related to session creation. errors updated above

Comment: Judging from the stack trace you probably are scanning for the same beans twice. Duplicating all your beans, one with transactional behavior (ignored) and one without (used). Make sure that the configuration used by the `DispatcherServlet` doesn't scan the same packages again as that will create the same bean twice!

Comment: In the `bean.setPackagesToScan("com.tracker");` define your POJO classes package. No, need to specify whole.

Comment: Thanks guys. working after all the changes above suggested